# Pluriharmonic is harmonic

Tags: several-complex-variables

I just started learning several complex variables and I'm a little bit confused. I just read that every pluriharmonic function is harmonic and I can't find any proof of that. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A function in *pluriharmonic* if its restriction to every complex line (one-dimensional affine subspace) is harmonic. In particular, a pluriharmonic function is harmonic in each (complex) variable separately, i.e.
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z_j\partial \bar z_j} = 0
$$
for each $j$. Hence
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z_j\partial \bar z_j} = 0
$$
so $f$ is indeed harmonic.

Comment: I don't see the equivalence of the partial derivative definition of pluriharmonic and the restriction to each complex line.